# Toggle className in React when map the array

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, classname

I have a problem toggling class when I map an array.

I have an array of products.

```
export const Products = [
  {
     id: 0,
     img: 'Star Wars',
     title: 'Star Wars: Battlefront',
     description: 'Immerse Yourself in the Ultimate Star Wars 
      Experience.',
     price: 300,
     isInBasket: false
  },
```

I use the useContext to pass the data

```
   const GamesProvider = ({ children }) => {
   const [games, setGames] = useState(Products);

   return (
      <GamesContext.Provider value={{ games }}>
         {children}
      </GamesContext.Provider>
   );
};
```

and here I map the array to show elements, I want to toggle class in div products__game by props game.isInBasket

```
 const productsList = gameCtx.games.map(game => (
      <div className={`products__game ${game.isInBasket ? '' : 'disabledd'}`} key={game.id}>
         <div className="products__game__image">
            <span>{game.img}</span>
         </div>
         <div className="products__game__description">
            <div className="products__game__description-container">
               <h3>{game.title}</h3>
               <span>{game.description}</span>
               <span>{game.price} Gil</span>
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => addProductToBasket(game.id)}>Add to Basket</button>
         </div>
      </div >
   ));
```

addProductToBasket

```
  const addProductToBasket = (id) => {
      const addProduct = gameCtx.games.find(el => el.id === id);
      cartCtx.addGame(addProduct)
   };
```

addGame

```
const cartReducer = (state = defaultCartState, action) => {
   if (action.type === 'ADD') {
      const updatedTotalAmount = state.totalAmount + Number(action.game.price);
      const game = action.game
      const updatedGame = {
         ...game,
         isInBasket: true,
      }
      const updatedGames = state.games.concat(updatedGame);

      return {
         games: updatedGames,
         totalAmount: updatedTotalAmount,
      }
   }
...
```

When I add the product to the basket then the 'isInBasket' field has changed to true, when I deleted the game is false so everything works but the div won't get the class.

```
<div className={`products__game ${game.isInBasket ? '' : 'disabledd'}`} key={game.id}>
```

Comment: please provide more code ! then we can check the problem

Comment: I'm sorry. I added more code.

Comment: Please provide code for `addProductToBasket`. Likely it mutates state directly.